# how download m3u file from url with all details for account iptv?

Tags: url, download, m3u8, m3u, iptv

how download m3u file from url with all details for account?
i get file from this url http://yourdomainiptv.com:8000/get.php?username=yourusername&password=yourpassword&type=m3u_plus&type=ts
and this file work but in i can't get the icone for groupe_title in file and i can't get where the account expired ?
i am working for iptv player project for android

Comment: That domain is invalid. In fact is available for purchase. There is no possible way to inform you how to download a file from a domain that does not exist.

Comment: yes this is a exemple domain ...

Comment: Well, ever domain authenticates differently. There is not a standard. Which makes this question unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the expiration date information of an IPTV M3U account, use this URL:

```
http://yourdomainiptv.com:8000/panel_api.php?username=yourusername&password=yourpassword
```

This URL will print all account information including the expiration date "exp_date", the value can be in timestamp, you will need to convert it to human readable format: you can use this online tool:
https://timestamp.online/

Answer (score 0):

Open in VLC and export the playlist as m3u8 if for smart tv etc.. or other protocol as required.

Answer (score 0):

Attention don't send your username and password in other site link. if you need to download m3u file, add "&output=ts&type=m3u_plus&output=ts" to your link.

exemple :
http://yourdomainiptv.com:8000/panel_api.php?username=yourusername&password=yourpassword&output=ts&type=m3u_plus&output=ts